# Need advice for running React app on linux server

Tags: nginx, docker

I'm stuck on this issue of running a react app on a clients Linux server. There is an existing site being hosted on this same server which is being served with nginx. My goal is to integrate the new web app at /new-app. I haven't had any success with this though. I've tried adding a new file for my app at /sites-enabled/ and /sites-available/ with nginx configs but the closest I've gotten is to get the app to display at the ipaddress/new-app. So I've looked into docker as a solution but am getting stuck there as-well as the only thing that is served is the nginx welcome page.

heres my nginx/docker files

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;  }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Stage 0, "build-stage", based on Node.js to build the frontend
FROM node:alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /app/
RUN npm run build

# Stage 1, based on NGINX to provide a configuration to be used with react-router
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx.html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Any advice/suggestions is greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For starters, a "site" in `sites-enabled` is actually a virtual host, so if you want to make your new application available under a path in an existing virtual host, you'll need to modify the configuration for that virtual host's `server` block, rather than create a separate configuration file in `sites-available`.

From there, it's a relatively straightforward HTTP reverse proxy configuration, as per [the fine manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).